# UILabel text customization

Tags: ios, uilabel, customization

[image]

I have to make this screen in iPhone app. I am using `UIScrollView` and `UILabel` to do this, but cannot be able to customize text in label like 'Q' and 'A' spacing from other text and blue color of email text. Can anybody help me? I found some customization libraries but not good to understand and use.

Comment: If it was me I would do this with a UITableView.

Answer (score 3):

Starting from iOS 6 you can use `Attributed String`, just create your UILabels in the Storyboard/UI Editor and customize them in the Attributes Inspector window on the right side. I would place an additional Label for the A and Q characters to have a fixed gap.

[image]

If you are working with an older iOS version, take a look at the [TTTAttributedLabel](https://github.com/mattt/TTTAttributedLabel). There are a couple of examples on the site, it's very easy to integrate and use it in your project.

Comment: under the scroll we cannot place Q A labels